# C++ Xcode assert evaluated in release

Tags: c++, xcode, release, assertions

I'm quite new to Xcode (and Mac in general). I started a little iPhone project - coding in C++ whatever possible - and just noted that my assert(); commands are executed also in release mode.

Is this a known problem and how do I solve it properly?

thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Xcode does not add -DNDEBUG for release mode automatically.

To add it, go to Project | Edit Project Settings.  You need to be on the Build tab and choose Configuration Release.  Add a new Preprocessing Macro of NDEBUG.

Comment: this option was not available in my settings. I had to add OTHERC_FLAGS myself, as described in this article: http://de-co-de.blogspot.com/2009/01/xcode-31-other-c-flags.html now it works

Comment: You should be able to see Preprocessor Macros in Project > Edit Active Target > Build, but if you add it at the project level, then it will be propagated to all targets, which is probably what you want.

Comment: Is this answer still relevant now with the latest XCode 6 ?

Comment: @Mic Still relevant in XCode 8.

Comment: This is nuts for anyone coming to this from the Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank gaud for stack overflow. You still have to do this manually on Xcode 14.2 ...